# Modify form input before submitting form in symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a form in which i am passing image in base64 format, now before submitting form i am converting image base64 to uploaded file object , which is working fine but now i want to validate the uploaded file image.
How to achieve this.
In my build form method i have added validation but its not working.
Right now want to restrict image to 2mb but its even allowing more than 2mb image to get uploaded.

```
     $builder
       ->add('picture', FileType::class, [
            'label' =>  $trans('user.picture.name'),
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => [
               // new Image(['mimeTypes' => ['image/jpeg']]),
                new File(['maxSize' => '2M', 'mimeTypes' => ['image/jpeg']]),
            ],
        ]);


function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{

    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    list(, $data['imagebase64']) = explode(',', $data['imagebase64']);

    $filePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'hijob');
    $image = base64_decode($data['imagebase64']);
    file_put_contents($filePath, $image);

    $photo = new UploadedFile(
        $filePath,
        'photo.jpeg',
        'image/jpeg'
    );

    $data['picture'] = $photo;
    $event->setData($data);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you want to use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert in Entity class. That should be done something like this.

```
**
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024k",
 *     mimeTypes = {...},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid ..."
 * )
 */
```

Check https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/File.html

Comment: My form does not have data class.